# android api issues while targetting multiple devices

Tags: android

I am having problem in uploading and file through `httppost` request. I am getting the desired result when i am running my app in android device having `api level 10`. but, when i am testing the same app i am getting the error in android device as well as emulator having api level 17. The issues that i am facing is i am getting the value of `items.gethLenght() = 1` when i am running my app in api level 10 but when i am running the same app in api level 17 i am getting value of `items.getLenght() = 0` Please help me to solve this issue.

```
public void uploadFileToServer()
 {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_context + "/response/responses");
                try {                       
                    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlString, "UTF-8");
                    httppost.setEntity(entity); 
                    httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
                    httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

                   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    if (response.getStatusLine() != null){

                        response_data= new ArrayList<String>();

                 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                    try
                    {
                        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
                        String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                        DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                        InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
                        inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
                        Document doc = db.parse(inStream);
                        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
                        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
                        NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("order");
                        for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++)
                        {
                            Node item = items.item(i);
                            NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
                            for (int j=0;j<properties.getLength();j++)
                            {
                                Node property = properties.item(j);
                                String name = property.getNodeName();
                                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
                                {
                                    try{
                                        response_data.add(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                                        response_data_data= response_data.toString();

                                    }
                                    catch(Exception nu)
                                    {
                                        nu.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }                       
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

 }
```

Comment: please help me as fast as possible. any kind of help will be welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Even though "not fast as possible", here's the answer anyway:

It's a bug. Above API level 10, getElementsByTagName() returns all descendant elements with the given Name. But in API Level 10 and below, getElementsByTagName() incorrectly includes the element itself on which the method is called.

In your case getElementsByTagName() returns exactly one element: "root" itself. Above API Level 10 it works correctly, returning an empty list, because it appears there are no descendant elements called "order".